# What is the difference between \s and [:space:] in PHP Regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, posix

In my PHP code I've been using `[:space:]` and `[:print:]` for matching space and non-space characters respectively. I however came across one case where `preg_match` was unable to find a match even though it should have. Replacing `[:space:]` with `\s` solved the problem. Due to this I realized all my other uses of `[:space:]` in the code could fail unexpectedly at some point in the future and so embarked on replacing all of them with `\s`.

My question is why did `[:space:]` fail where `\s` worked? The original regexp was:

```
'%\[/row\][[:space:]]+<!-- related_products_section -->[[:space:][:print:]]+<!-- end_related_products_section -->%m'
```

which I changed into:

```
'%\[/row\][\s]+<!-- related_products_section -->[\s[:print:]]+<!-- end_related_products_section -->%m'
```

Another question arising is what is the non-posix equivalent of `[:print:]`?

Comment: `[:space:]` is a ERE-compatibility placeholder. It's the same as `\s` normally (depending on PCRE version), but becomes equivalent to `\p{Xps}` in `/u` Unicode mode.